# How can I get a Table View to register taps when each cell has an Image View covering it?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to create table view cells each with a UIImageView serving as a background for them. However, when I tap on each cell the table view will not register the click and will not transition to the view controller I have hooked up, even while I'm using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function.

I realize it's probably an issue with the ImageView obstructing the table views ability to register the cell tap. The cells will transition however when I drag my finger/mouse on it from left to right, just not on taps. I tried to use a Tap Gesture Recognizer on the Image View however it only worked for the cell at the very top and not all of them. How do I tackle this issue?

Here is an image of the table view cells so you have an idea of what I'm working with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKNK3.jpg. Thank you!

Comment: what you can also do is create a button of your image size and add image to your button .Else you can use tap gesture.

Comment: The ImageView shouldn't be obstructing anything. Can you show me the layout structure inside the storyboard?

Comment: @TusharSharma If I created a button and put an image within it, do I have to call the segue within the didSelectRow function or within the action function for the button?

Comment: @Sethmr Perhaps it's not the ImageView causing the problem? Here's the storyboard layout though. http://i.imgur.com/0cWxg3O.png

Comment: Uncheck user interaction enabled on the image.

Comment: If you are using didselect then image should not cause this issue as mentioned by @Sethmr .Else if not yes you need to do segue from button action.

Comment: @Sethmr I found the issue was not due to the Image View but the table view in general. I simply can't click on a cell and have it transition, I need to press down and swipe my mouse right to left for it to actually transition. Any thoughts?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you uncheck User Interaction Enabled on your Image View, the problem should be solved. When running into a problem always check the user interaction of the most child view and work your way up.

One trick I have also learned is to create a subclass of a child and override `touchesShouldCancel` like so:

```
override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    print("touchesShouldCancel")
    //Run extra code that you want when the user selects this view
    //then still retrieve the tap by its parent.
    return false
}
```

I am unsure of exactly what your problem is, but I would delete whatever segue that you have, add a new one by dragging from the yellow circle on the left side of the center portion of the top of your `tableView` ViewController inside the storyboard, to the `viewController` that you desire it to segue to. Give the segue an appropriate identifier, and then inside your `tableView` class under `tableView didSelectRow` add `performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChosenIdentifier", sender: indexPath)`

Then in `prepare forSegue` add in:

```
if let vc = sender.destination as? TheViewControllerYouAreSegueingTo {
    if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
        vc.variableIdentifyingWhatCellWasClicked = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

with whatever adjustment is needed to meet your specific needs.